# how to Create a AutoIncrement as id with a start value of 1 and end value of 1000

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a table where I just want to put 1000 record and my table has only two field Id(autoincrement).

Comment: in my table I have two table ID(autoincrement), name

Comment: so what's your question? you want to create a table and .. ?

Comment: I think the only thing that can work for you is the trigger. Just create a trigger to throw an error if there are already 1000 rows in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You do not mention what you are using, but I am assuming you are in SQL.  I do not believe you can limit the number of records in a table by the table configuration.  What you can do is, create a table then create the 1000 records. Then you can use a stored procedure to only do updates to the table or you may be able to use triggers to only allow update commands on the table.  I found these ideas on a different question.
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/141789/how-to-limit-maximum-number-of-rows-in-a-table-to-just-1